# Populate previous months name in dropdown in asp.net c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to populate previous months name including current month. i.e from March 2018 till February 2017. I have used addmonth function for returning month name but somewhere I'm facing hard to apply my logic here.

```
private void loadmonthlst()
{
    DropDownMonth.Items.Clear();
    int currentmonth = DateTime.Now.AddHours(13).Month;

    for (int month = currentmonth-1; month >= -12; month--)
    {
        string monthName = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(month).ToString("MMMM yyyy");
        DropDownMonth.Items.Add(new ListItem(monthName));
    }
}
```

This dropdown starts from may 2018. I subracted -2 from month, but i want the cleanest way to get this done

Comment: Just to be clear, the logic you have posted above does work for you, right?

Comment: Why the `.AddHours(13)`?

Comment: Yes it does work, but its starts from May 2018 @Nisarg

Comment: .AddHours(13) is due to the US server @ManfredRadlwimmer

Comment: @user100020 Ouch. You might want to handle that with timezones instead of manually adding that in. Especially when daylight saving time comes around, that might come back at you.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be starting with your currentmonth because `month` will be positive in the beginning and that's gonna add months, not go back (like you want), here's how to fix it:

```
for (int month = 0; month >= -12; month--)
{
    string monthName = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(month).ToString("MMMM yyyy");
    Console.WriteLine(monthName);
}
```

This gives from Mars 2018 to Mars 2017, if you want it to stop at Feb 2017 then just replace `month >= -12` with `month >= -13`.

Comment: Thank you @Haytam